# 500 Internal server error in wp admin ,at update & plugin (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, internal-server-error

I'm having Internal server error in some sessions(parts) after I login in wp dashboard.

Issues are in `wp-admin/plugins.php` and some few other places where is relating with any plugins.
I have checked `.htaccess`, memory limit to my server and in wp file is ok, I have deactivated all the plugins, changed themes, updated WordPress and still have the same issue.

I have check the error log and this is what it shows:

> [Thu Jun 09 12:22:25 2016] [error] [client 217.73.141.38] Premature end of script headers: update-core.php, referer: http://www.salus.al/wp-admin/
>
> [Thu Jun 09 12:22:29 2016] [warn] [client 217.73.141.38] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server, referer: http://www.salus.al/wp-admin/
>
> [Thu Jun 09 12:22:29 2016] [error] [client 217.73.141.38] Premature end of script headers: plugins.php, referer: http://www.salus.al/wp-admin/
>
> [Thu Jun 09 12:22:32 2016] [warn] [client 217.73.141.38] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server, referer: http://www.salus.al/wp-admin/

Comment: There is no such file called `wp-adminplugins.php` in WordPress.

Comment: It was an orthographic mistake.

Comment: Try to update wp-admin and wp-includes folders from latest fresh WordPress. It should solve your issue.

Comment: No buddy ,I already did it and nothing changed.

Answer (score 1):

Remove or rename your plugins folder and see if the problem goes away. If it does, then add each plugin one at a time to see which one produces the error. Perhaps clear all cache, cookies, etc as well.